# C# Console App -- Trying to access a list from else statement

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, sorting

This is for a data structures and algorithms class.  We're just starting out with bubble sort.  The instructions were to generate random, unique integers and sort them using the sorting technique of the lecture.  It will be required to add different sorting techniques as well.

To generate the list of random numbers, I generated a list and then shuffled the list using the fisher-yates algorithm.  So I have my unique, sorted list of whatever size I choose.

I'm getting stuck because after I generate the random list, I am having problems accessing the list to run it through BubbleSort.

Is there any way I can do this?

```
 class Algorithms
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {         

        string response = "";

        //Main Console Menu
        while (response != "exit") 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type help for list of commands");
            response = Console.ReadLine();
           //List<int> toSort = new List<int>();

            if (response.StartsWith("exit"))
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            else if (response.ToLower().StartsWith("help"))
            {
                Help(response);
            }

            else if (response.ToLower().StartsWith("generate"))
            {

            // Shuffle(Generate(response));
            // have been using the line above but adding next line for
            //an idea of my problem

            List<int> toSort = Shuffle(Generate(response));

            }

            else if (response.ToLower().StartsWith("bubble"))
            {
                //This doesn't work and I'm trying to figure out how it can
                BubbleSort(toSort); 

            }                           

        }
    }


    //Displays help information 
    public static void Help(string input)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("\ngenerate <integer>   --  Generates a data set of intended amount of integers\n"+
            "algorithm <algorithm type>  -- Choose which algorithm to sort data\nexit   --   exit application\n" ); 
        }

    //Generates List of integers from 0 to number choosen by user
    public static List<int> Generate(string size)
    {
        int cutString = size.Length - 9; 
        string sizeSubset = size.Substring(9, cutString);            
        List<int> numGen = new List<int>();
        int dataSetSize = Convert.ToInt32(sizeSubset); 
        for(int i = 0; i <= dataSetSize; i++)
        {
            numGen.Add(i);
          // Console.WriteLine(numGen[i]);                

        }

        return numGen;                  

    }

    //Use Fisher-Yates algorithm to shuffle the list. 
    static Random randomize = new Random();
    public static List<int> Shuffle(List<int>makeRandom)
    {

        List<int> shuffled = new List<int>();
        int n = makeRandom.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = randomize.Next(n + 1);
            int value = makeRandom[k];
            makeRandom[k] = makeRandom[n];
            makeRandom[n] = value;
            shuffled.Add(value);
            Console.WriteLine(value);

        }

        return shuffled;

    }

    public static void BubbleSort(List<int>input)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= input.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= (input.Count - 1); j++)
            {
                if (input[j] > input[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = input[j];
                    input[j] = input[j + 1];
                    input[j + 1] = temp;
                    Console.WriteLine("hello");
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Well yes, you've generated the list - but you haven't stored a reference to it anywhere... think about having a local variable in `Main` storing a reference to the list.

Comment: How exactly would I do that in C#?  That's kind of what I've been working on but haven't really found any answers.

Comment: Well I've already given you a hint: you need a local variable in your `Main` method. But you need to make sure that variable is still in scope in the `"bubble"` case, so you need to declare it outside the `while` loop...

Comment: Thanks, didn't quite understand what you meant. I read it an initially thought of pointers. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined list in scope of `else if (response.ToLower().StartsWith("generate"))` code block, so it is not accessible outside of that block. Move declaration to `Main` method scope, like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{         

    string response = "";
    //define your list here.
    List<int> toSort = new List<int>();

    //Main Console Menu
    while (response != "exit") 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type help for list of commands");
        response = Console.ReadLine();

        if (response.StartsWith("exit"))
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        else if (response.ToLower().StartsWith("help"))
        {
            Help(response);
        }

        else if (response.ToLower().StartsWith("generate"))
        {
            toSort = Shuffle(Generate(response));
        }

        else if (response.ToLower().StartsWith("bubble"))
        {

            List<int> sortedList = BubbleSort(toSort); 
        }                           

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had something very similar before but declared it incorrectly. Problem solved!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, you could mark my answer as a solution; as a way to say thanks on SO :)